# Creating a postgres container with schema, tables

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to launch a postgres database container. When container gets launched, I also want the schema and tables to be created in it.

I am trying to copy .sql file into docker entrypoint.

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_DB MY_APP_DB
COPY my-app-db-ddl.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**DDL file contents:**

```
CREATE SCHEMA MY_APP_DB;

CREATE TABLE MY_APP_DB.ACCESS_MASTER
(
    "ACCESS_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "ROLE_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
);
```

Above script helping to create Database but not schema/tables. How can I achieve this?

Please help.

My container logs :

```
2020-08-05 08:49:25.428 UTC [47] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-05 08:49:25 UTC
2020-08-05 08:49:25.433 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
CREATE DATABASE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/imcsysdb.sql
CREATE SCHEMA
CREATE TABLE


2020-08-05 08:49:25.654 UTC [46] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
waiting for server to shut down....2020-08-05 08:49:25.656 UTC [46] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-08-05 08:49:25.657 UTC [46] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 53) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-05 08:49:25.658 UTC [48] LOG:  shutting down
2020-08-05 08:49:25.675 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2020-08-05 08:49:25.768 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-05 08:49:25.769 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2020-08-05 08:49:25.769 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2020-08-05 08:49:25.772 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-08-05 08:49:25.789 UTC [73] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-05 08:49:25 UTC
2020-08-05 08:49:25.794 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: I didn't get what exactly you are referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.Dockerfile

```
from postgres
```

1. correct the error in the sql:

```
CREATE SCHEMA MY_APP_DB;

CREATE TABLE MY_APP_DB.ACCESS_MASTER
(
    "ACCESS_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "ROLE_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
);
```

2. create a directory in your local and mount with docker as `-v /opt/import1:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

cat /opt/import/setup.sql

```
root@ubuntu:/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/docker/postgres# cat /opt/import1/setup.sql 
create schema my_app_db;
CREATE TABLE my_app_db.access_master ("ACCESS_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,"ROLE_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

```
root@ubuntu:/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/docker/postgres# cat Dockerfile 
from postgres

root@ubuntu:/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/docker/postgres# docker images
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
sathyadev/postgres   latest              683dd2ba4015        About an hour ago   313MB
postgres             latest              4b52913b0a3a        8 days ago          313MB

docker run --name 683dd2ba4015 -p 5432:5432 -v /opt/import1:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust -d postgres

root@ubuntu:/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/docker/postgres# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
53a6f7972b91        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   683dd2ba4015
```

3. verify the

```
postgres=# set schema 'my_app_db';
SET
postgres=# select * from access_master;
 ACCESS_ID | ROLE_ID 
-----------+---------
(0 rows)

postgres=#
```

full logs for your reference,

```
root@ubuntu:/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/docker/postgres# cat Dockerfile 
from postgres

root@ubuntu:/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/docker/postgres# docker build --tag sathyadev/postgres:0.1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/1 : from postgres
 ---> 4b52913b0a3a
Successfully built 4b52913b0a3a
Successfully tagged sathyadev/postgres:0.1
root@ubuntu:/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/docker/postgres# docker images
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
postgres             latest              4b52913b0a3a        11 days ago         313MB
sathyadev/postgres   0.1                 4b52913b0a3a        11 days ago         313MB
root@ubuntu:/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/docker/postgres# docker run --name 4b52913b0a3a -p 5432:5432 -v /opt/import1:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust -d postgres
d4709527d3f42393cf5a857ebd650d582da918ef964075b418a63f5acef17516
root@ubuntu:/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/docker/postgres# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
d4709527d3f4        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   4b52913b0a3a
root@ubuntu:/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/docker/postgres# docker exec -ti d4709527d3f4 bash
root@d4709527d3f4:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  docker-entrypoint-initdb.d  docker-entrypoint.sh  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@d4709527d3f4:/# su postgres
postgres@d4709527d3f4:/$ psql
psql (12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# set schema 'my_app_db';
SET
postgres=# select * from access_master
postgres-# ;
 ACCESS_ID | ROLE_ID 
-----------+---------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Hi @smart_coder, Can you please tell what shud be put in Dockerfile. I tried above steps . But it is not creating tables. Something amiss

Comment: Can you share the docker run command you tried?? And SQL file also

Comment: sudo docker run -d --name myapp-postgres-container  -p 5432:5432 -v /opt/pg_import:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ myapp-postgres-image

Comment: create schema my_app_db;
CREATE TABLE my_app_db.access_master ("ACCESS_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,"ROLE_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

Comment: In `/opt/import/setup.sql` have you added thr following - `create schema my_app_db; CREATE TABLE my_app_db.access_master ("ACCESS_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,"ROLE_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default"); `

Comment: `ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres 
ENV POSTGRES_DB MY_APP_DB`. these two lines are not required.

Comment: Yes. I have added above query in /opt/import/setup.sql. But Dockerfile is placed in a different path.

Comment: can you post the logs of the given command - `docker logs myapp-postgres-container`

Comment: my docker container logs are: 
`server started

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
CREATE ROLE
GRANT
CREATE SCHEMA
CREATE TABLE` my docker file is  cat Dockerfile 
`from postgres`

Comment: Hi @smartcoder. Thanks much for your patience in helping me out. But I am terribly going wrong somewhere. Have posted the container logs above. Please check and guide me

Comment: When I check for \t after getting into database it says 'No relations'. But database is getting created

Comment: `set schema 'my_app_db'; ` and `select * from my_app_db.access_master` retrieved the results for me. 
As per the Docker container logs, `done
server started
CREATE DATABASE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/imcsysdb.sql
CREATE SCHEMA
CREATE TABLE` your local sql ran inside the docker container and schema & tables got created. so mentioned issue got fixed.
 Please accept this answer for your question and raise a new question  for `No relations` will check please raise a new issue for that.